# Javascript and MVC return types

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have this JavaScript in a page of an ASP.Net MVC project:

```
function showAllianceMembers_onclick() {
    var strName = $("#allianceNameTextBox").val();

    $.ajax(
    {
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Alliance/Index",
        data: "allianceName=" + strName,
        success: function (result) {
            if (result.success) {
                alert("done!");
            }
            else {
                alert("error!!");
            }
        },
        error: function (req, status, error) {
            alert(error);
        }
    });
}
```

As you know, this script is calling a `MVC Action`. here is the `MVC Action`:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(string allianceName)
{
    //Populating an object containing a list (IList)

    return View(res);
}
```

The problem here is that the JavaScript code just shows the alert with ERROR message... 
What's wrong in my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your controller action you are not sending JSON, but a simple view. So there is no `.success` property defined on the `result` variable. Here's how your AJAX request could look like:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/Alliance/Index",
    data: { allianceName: strName },
    success: function (result) {
        // If you got so far the AJAX request succeeded, the result variable
        // will contain the final HTML of the rendered view
        alert("done!");
    },
    error: function (req, status, error) {
        alert(error);
    }
});
```

or if you want to send JSON from your controller action:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(string allianceName)
{
    // populate the result        
    return Json(new { success = true, result = res });
}
```

and then:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/Alliance/Index",
    data: { allianceName: strName },
    success: function (result) {
        if (result.success) {
            // do something with result.res
            alert("done!");
        }
    },
    error: function (req, status, error) {
        alert(error);
    }
});
```

Comment: Should I change the `ActionResult` to `JSonResult`?

Comment: @Dr TJ, no you shouldn't. The Json method returns a JsonResult which in turn derives from ActionResult. So for being more generic keep ActionResult in your action signature.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are trying to retrieve data, not HTML markup.
Try this:

```
$.ajax(
{
    type: "POST",
    url: "/Alliance/Index",
    data: { 'allianceName' : strName },
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (result) {
        if (result.success) {
            alert("done!");
        }
        else {
            alert("error!!");
        }
    },
    error: function (req, status, error) {
        alert(error);
    }
});
```

And update this also:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult Index(string allianceName)
{
    //Populating an object containing a list (IList)

    return new JsonResult { Data = res };
}
```

Comment: He doesn't return JSON from his action but a view which is HTML.

Comment: Ah, you have updated your answer to take into account my comment, removing my downvote.

Comment: @Darin, You don't know what he actually intended to return.  I have a feeling that's actually the problem - he's trying to fetch some data, but instead is returning the view.

Comment: yes, that's why I presented both solutions when I answered this question. When you answered your question you only suggested that he uses JSON, but you didn't indicate that the action code should be modified as well.

Comment: I'm slow... takes me a while to line up all my ducks.  :)

Comment: Thanks so much for your answers. what I wanted to do was fetching some items and updating a table in view using JavaScript. Both are right and thanks again.

Comment: You may also want to check out jQuery templates to do client-side data binding of the data you return from the AJAX call to the HTML table:  http://api.jquery.com/category/plugins/templates/